# Trouble with CommandLineToArgvW Windows Function in Assembly

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, command-line

I am trying just to print out the value of **argc** using the **CommandLineToArgvW** Window's API function in NASM. The following is what I have:

```
extern _ExitProcess@4
extern _GetCommandLineA@0
extern _CommandLineToArgvW@8
extern printf

global _start
section .code

Format:
    db "%d",10,0
FormatS:
    db "%s",10,0
_start:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 4 ; Create empty space for ArgC
    call _GetCommandLineA@0
    push eax; Push value beneath ArgC
    mov ebx, ebp ; Set ebx to ebp
    sub ebx, 4
    push dword ebx ; pushes ArgC address onto stack
    push dword [ebp - 8] ; pushes pointer to Command Line String
    call _CommandLineToArgvW@8
    push dword [ebp - 4]
    push Format
    call printf
    push dword 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

No matter what I do, the value for argc is 1. What am I doing wrong?

I assemble and link with these commands:

```
nasm -fwin32 FunctionTests.asm
golink FunctionTests.obj kernel32.dll msvcrt.dll shell32.dll /console /entry _start
FunctionTests.exe hi asdf asdf asdf asdf
```

As you can see, from the last line, argc should be 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change _GetCommandLineA to _GetCommandLine**W** CommandLineToArgv expects a pointer to a UNICODE string.

MASM but just about the same:

```
start:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    call    GetCommandLineW

    lea     ecx, dword ptr[ebp - 4] ; need the address of local
    push    ecx                     ; address of local
    push    eax                     ; pointer to unicode string
    call    CommandLineToArgvW

    push    dword ptr [ebp - 4]     ; value of local
    push    offset Format
    call    crt_printf
    add     esp, 8

    ; this is all?  Then we don't have to restore stack.
    push    0
    call    ExitProcess
end start
```

and this is the output:

D:\Projects>ConTest.exe boo boo I see you

6

D:\Projects>

Answer (score 3):

Set a breakpoint just before you call `CommandLineToArgvW` and inspect the parameters you're about to pass. Observe that the first parameter you are passing is not a pointer to a string. It is a pointer to a pointer to a string.

Comment: Although that was a problem it is still not working. I am making the change though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **GetCommandLineW** rather than **GetCommandLineA**.

Answer (score 2):

You are using *CommandLineToArgvW* with an **ANSI** string, use *GetCommandLineW* to get the command line in unicode.

You are also not dereferencing the pointer to the command line:

```
push ebx ; pushes ArgC address onto stack
```